# Icon themes not fully applied

Tags: themes, icons

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I've installed Faenza icons (version 1.3.1) and used the latest Ubuntu Tweak to apply the theme. However, Faenza icons are not fully applied and I can still see some icons have their old, system default appearance. How can I fix this?

Screenshot example:

[image]

You can see in the screenshot here the icons for Displays, Power, Time & Date, and Sound are stuck with Ubuntu's system default ones, and I don't want that.

Comment: I have tried logging in and out, restarting the system, and re-applying the icon theme but it did nothing to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If an app/config does not have a corresponding icon in the `/usr/share/icons/Faenza*` directories, it defaults to the originals which you are seeing.

For example, the 'User Accounts' corresponds to `config-users.svg` and the 'Universal Access' corresponds to `access.svg`.

It is likely that the icons for those bits are simply not there/were not created by the Faenza author.  You can have a look through or raise a bug yourself on the Launchpad:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/~tiheum

If you are feeling dedicated, you can create your own icons; then find out what names they correspond to in the ambience icons folder and save yours to the corresponding location in the Faenza folder.

Comment: I used Faenza icons since 12.04 and the icons for the originals I'm seeing right now are covered by the theme. Only now in 14.04 problems like this happens.

Comment: That may indicate that the icon paths that the settings window is looking for has changed which isn't unusual between version.  I haven't looked through the source code to say enough so don't quote me on that. :)

Comment: so is there any way I can make the icon path normal and the theme to work perfectly?

Answer (score 0):

you can change them manually.

1. the installed faenza icons are located in `/usr/share/icons/Faenza`
2. from terminal: `gedit /usr/share/applications/yourappname.desktop`
3. change the `Icon=yourappname` to `Icon=/usr/share/icons/Faenza/yourappname` and save!